# What would be a good way to show activity title without actionbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Im making an app for android, without actionbar. 
What is best practice for showing titles without actionbar?

Comment: Sorry, but i can't help to ask. Why you don't want an actionbar, if you still want to display a title? Maybe you just need to "style" your actionbar the way you need, instead of removing it from the app.

Comment: Most of the layouts in the app are best shown in full screen, but this one activity could maybe use a descriptive title, so i just want to test some alternatives. At this point it would take too much time to set up the actionbar before the deadline.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is basically never using an action bar. This gives you a complete device screen to play with.
You can use images or different text styles for showing the title. You can also use interesting icons.

To remove action bar -

Go to res > values > styles.xml

Here is an illustration of styles file -

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The app is almost done, already without actionbar. Just want to see if some type of description could help one of the layouts. Though, i thought actionbar was best practice, even when i removed it during development.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Toolbar (it's like the action bar, but more flexible). For example, action bar needs to be on top of the screen, but toolbar can have place anywhere in the layout.

You title can be shown as text or a beautiful asset.

If, for some reason, you don't want to use the toolbar, you can think about something like having a scrollView with the title on top of it.

Comment: First time developing for Android, so all the widgets and features are overwhelming. Did not know about Toolbar. Will check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular LinearLayout with a TextView inside. Style according to your needs, and set the text in the xml, or programmaticaly using TextView's setText() method.

Comment: That is an alternative, yes. But i was looking for something more creative. For now the queryhint in the top searchview will do hopefully.